# How to enumerate all apps that are shown in apps switch list in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

It was possible to rely on running processes on windows 8, but since windows 8.1 corresponding process may run while the app is not displayed in the apps switch list.